# How do Google opening links in a new window without target attribute?

Tags: hyperlink

i wonder how google manages to open external links in a new window/tab without defining target="_blank".

For example in google plus, all external links open in a new window.
I think its some Javascript voodoo but the .js code is obfuscated so i cant really look into.

edit: oh and followup question: why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a framework makes this easy. Just have JavaScript look for links marked `rel="external"`, or another identifier that shows them to be an external link, and dynamically add `target="blank"`. Here's an example using Prototype:

```
$$('a[rel="external"]').each(function(a) {
  a.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
};
```

Comment: thx for the explaination. I wonder why they do this? the target blank attribute is deprecated i think, so whats the point in sneaking it in afterwards?

Comment: But that requires having inserted the class in advance.  Unless there's a *lot* of links on the page, it's often easiest to just loop through **all** of the links, examine the URL, and filter out those that shouldn't be modified.  You can also play with negation & attribute selectors in CSS3 ( eg, `a.not([href^="http://example.com/"])` to get all links that aren't to a given domain, but it's easier to deal with https & subdomains in javascript).  ps., you want `_blank`, or you'll end up pushing all links into the same window.

Comment: @Joe Thanks for pointing that out. It is now fixed. Your solution is just as viable as mine. But the point of the code was to show how it works in theory. The best way to do it would be a whole different question itself.

Answer (score 0):

It's not beyond reasoning for them to add the target attribute by javascript before allowing the anchor link event to return true.

Answer (score 0):

It's Javascript. You can say:

```
window.open('http://example.org', '_blank').focus();
```

But please, **don't**. Opening links in new windows is almost always the wrong thing to do. Seriously, good uses of this are vanishingly few. If users want a link opened in a new window, they are quite capable of doing that themselves.

Jakob Nielsen was [telling people this twelve years ago](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/990530.html). [Others](http://www.trilithium.com/johan/2005/03/target-blank/) [have](http://diveintoaccessibility.org/day_16_not_opening_new_windows.html) [taken](http://www.smackthemouse.com/20030831) [up](http://blog.choppingblock.com/2009/06/the-ever-raging-battle-about-target_blank/) [the](http://doteduguru.com/id1765-user-experience-and-target_blank.html) [cudgels](http://www.thatwebguyblog.com/post/dont_use_target_blank). The W3C removed the `target` attribute from [HTML 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2) because it was such a bad idea. I honestly don't understand how this usage persists. Don't you find it incredibly annoying when a website does this to you? Why would you want to write a website which does this to someone else?

Which brings me to your followup question. Why did Google decide to do this? I have no answer to that, and i am completely and utterly baffled how one of the very biggest, brightest, web companies could make such an elementary mistake. But then, a lot of the Google Plus interface has very poor usability (as in, mostly worse than Facebook poor); i suspect there is an interesting story behind it. Was the project under-resourced, and thus built cheaply on top of a rapid development framework such as GWT? Was it built as a spare time project by a lone wolf with a blind spot for web architecture? Was it driven by strategy wonks who didn't care about getting the technology right? Mystery.

Comment: New window - annoying. New tab - not annoying. Actually, for me it's even more annoying when I *want* to open in a new tab and the site won't let me, because of Javascript links.

Comment: I'm right there with you. I dont want to use it, iam only wonder why google use it in that hacky way. Iam aware that its deprecated and it was a bad decision all the time to use this attribute. Only curious on this topic.

Comment: @UncleZeiv: You're absolutely right about JS links stopping you opening new tabs (or windows). Those are indeed a crime worse than forcing a new tab or window. However, i still find forcing a new tab to be annoying; less annoying than forcing a new window, but still annoying. Also annoying is pages which grab focus when opened, which interferes with effective tabbed browsing. The bottom line is that links should be links, and it should be up to the user to open them in a new window or tab if they want.

Comment: @Michele: They "why" is a good question, but i suspect you won't get a good answer here, unless someone from the Google Plus team reads this question. Much as i hate to say it, you would be more likely to get an answer to that part of the question on [Quora](http://www.quora.com/).

Comment: Thx Tom, unfortunately i dont have an invitation to Quora. But anyways, sometimes you must accept things how they are.

Comment: Do you need an invitation? I don't think you do. As for accepting things how they are, well, "All I know is that first, you've got to get mad" ...